# Green's function for a differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

I am having a hard time with the following problem:

$$
y\mapsto Ly=-\frac{d}{dx}(x\frac{d}{dx}y) 
$$
with boundary conditions $y(1)=0$ and $y^\prime(2)=0$.

There are 2 things to do here:

1. I have to determine a fundamental matrix for the differential equation $Ly=0$.
2. I have to determine the green's function of L for these given boundary conditions and the intervall (1,2).

I have exam in this subject and our professor is bringing stuff to the exam, which we did not have done in the lectures. I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.

Comment: For the green's function, it's easiest to work backwards, especially when you have the operator in a form that is easily undone one by one. Start with delta function on the other side, then integrate, etc, keeping the constants at every integration.

Comment: @NinadMunshi after doing the delta function i get: $-\frac{d}{dx}y-x\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y$, how should I continue? do i have to integrate two times? sorry if my questions are too stupid

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti I just don't know how to proceed, I am lost :-(

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti I know what a fundamental matrix is. But in this case I really dont know how to solve the differential equation, because of the composition of the derivatives. usually I take a look at the characteristical polynom of the differential equation and than determine the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors. But I dont know if I can apply the same method in this case

Comment: I guess I have to integrate it for a second time, so I get $\frac{x^2}{2}\cdot y= c_1\cdot x + c_2$ if I didnt make a mistake. How do i get the fundamental matrix now?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Ok thank you, I have figured it out and already determined the greens function. Thank you very much for your patience and help :-) Sometimes I feel like an idiot :D